# href an excel sheet and save changes made to it. using jsp javascript html

Tags: javascript, jsp

I hace an Excel sheet. using html i am opening it as

```
 href="other/Browser-Capture.xls" target="_blank"><img src="images/xlsimg.bmp"></a>
```

This opens the excel sheet in a new browser window. I am however not able to modify it.
any idea how it can that be done...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When requesting a file from a server (like the Excel sheet), it is downloaded to your local computer. If you edit it there, your edits do not affect the Excel file on the server.

So editing it directly on the server using a browser is **not possible**.

You could add an upload functionality to your webpage where you can upload the changed excel file using `<input type="file">`. However this might get difficult because you would need to ensure that the uploaded file is the same as the original one.

If you want your users to be able to edit data on your webserver, you could save this data in a file, database etc. and provide a **form** to the users where they can edit the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried opening the file using ActiveEx object.. It works fine but then we need to make changes to IE settings.. The form option looks good... :)